# How to get Wi-Fi entry dialogue box to appear on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet

I’m having trouble connecting to the hotel WiFi. It is unlocked and not secured, but when you try to connect, usually a dialogue box opens and tells you to input a password and then you will be connected to the Internet. This box is not showing up anymore.

The first time I tried using Terminal and the command `ifconfig` and changing the MAC address by one digit. However this stopped working. I am getting the response

> ifconfig:ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): device power is off.

I have done this following the steps to turn Wi-Fi off. Then opened Terminal, then put in the code, then turned Wi-Fi back on.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try opening this URL in Safari: http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed if the hotel's wifi connection requires logging in via a connection splash page in the browser? 
(I would post this as a comment, but I can't)